# Winforms insert image into ListView / ImageList at index

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, imagelist

Winforms, C#, VS2017

ImageList does not have an Insert method (however ListViewItemCollection does). I have tried a few different ways to insert a new image into the middle of a ListView and it's LargeImageList, but not getting it to work quite properly.

Anyone have any tried and true code that works properly?

This is what I have, but the images don't get synced properly to the items in the list.

```
    protected void InsertThumbnail(string key, string keySelected)
    {
        var newImageList = new ImageList()
        {
            ImageSize = new Size(thumbWidth, thumbHeight)
        };
        var itemNew = new ListViewItem();
        var foundSelected = false;

        //lvAllPages.BeginUpdate();

        for (int i = 0; i < lvAllPages.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = lvAllPages.Items[i];
            newImageList.Images.Add(item.Tag.ToString(), lvAllPages.LargeImageList.Images[i]);

            if (item.Tag.ToString() == keySelected)
            {
                var image = batch.GetThumbnail(key);
                newImageList.Images.Add(key, image);
                itemNew = new ListViewItem()
                {
                    BackColor = Color.Aquamarine,
                    ImageIndex = i,
                    Tag = key,
                };

                if (isLocal)
                    itemNew.Text = $"{GetFileName(key)} (insert) - {itemNew.ImageIndex}";

                foundSelected = true;
            }

            if (foundSelected)
            {
                item.ImageIndex = item.ImageIndex + 1;
                if (isLocal)
                    item.Text = $"{GetFileName(item.Tag.ToString())} - {item.ImageIndex}";
            }
        }

        lvAllPages.LargeImageList.Dispose();
        lvAllPages.LargeImageList = newImageList;
        lvAllPages.Items.Insert(itemNew.ImageIndex, itemNew);
    }
```

One more related thing, but not pertinent to the problems I am having.  For anyone looking at this question and having similar issues, this helped with the issue of sorting items after inserting a new one. Default behavior when you insert a new ListViewItem at a given index, it will appear at the bottom of the list. I found this handy class to keep items sorted by index, which solved that problem:

class CompareByIndex : IComparer
{
    private readonly ListView _listView;

```
public CompareByIndex(ListView listView)
{
    this._listView = listView;
}
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    int i = this._listView.Items.IndexOf((ListViewItem)x);
    int j = this._listView.Items.IndexOf((ListViewItem)y);
    return i - j;
}
```

}

And in the form load:

lvAllPages.ListViewItemSorter = new CompareByIndex(lvAllPages);

Comment: I would ignore the index and just use the string keys.

Comment: I think I tried just using the string keys, but I needed index for other methods that either rotate or replace the image...  I may revisit that idea, though.

Comment: The thing with ListViewItem is that Key and ImageIndex are mutually exclusive, you can only use one or the other.  If you set both, one is defaulted back to 0 (ImageIndex), or empty string (Key).

Comment: Right.  Ignore the index and use the string key.

Comment: And because I need both, I store the filepath in ListViewItem.Tag, and also use the ListViewItem.ImageIndex.  I have other methods that either rotate or replace the image, and I think I need the index for those...  I at least need the index for sorting being that the ListView doesn't sort itself.

Comment: Inserting an image would displace all items that rely on the indices instead of the keys. Which is why you shouldn't want it..

Comment: Displacing is what I want.  For example, if list contains 8 items, and user selects 3rd item in list, they click a button to insert new image after the 3rd item. Also, I need to store the filepath for each image.

Comment: FWIW: its not necessary to have the image lists in the same order as the listview items are displayed. The traditional way of solving this is to add the image at the end of the image list, then create the item with the index of that location. So if there initially were 10 items, with image indices 0-9, you'd add image at end, which is index 10, , create item with ImageIndex = 10, then insert that item whereever you want into the list. That's why `ListViewItemCollection` has an `Insert`, but `Images` does not. Its not needed. Related, you can delete an Item, without deleting its Image.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, that's a design decision. `ImageList.Images` is a [`ImageCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) and as such, it implements the  [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface.

Unfortunately, the [`Insert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2) method is allowed to throw a `NotSupportedException`. And that's what the list will do when used like a `IList`:

```
((IList)imageList.Images).Insert(5, new Bitmap(10,10));
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

In order to have the images shown in a specific order, use the `Add()` method which takes the key:

```
imageList.Images.Add("1", new Bitmap(100,100));
```

That should also enable you to replace the image:

```
imageList.Images.RemoveByKey("1");
imageList.Images.Add("1", new Bitmap(200,200));
```

For that to work, you need to set the Sorting property:

```
listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

For storing additional information like path etc. use anotther data structure with the same key.

---

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ImageList imageList = new ImageList();
    Dictionary<string, Metadata> metadata = new Dictionary<string, Metadata>();
    private string dir = @"H:\temp";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // You would set this in the designer, probably
        listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
        listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;

        // Make sure we start from the beginning
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        imageList.Images.Clear();
        metadata.Clear();

        // Add items
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var filename = "1 ("+(i+1)+").png"; // Just strange names I have
            var fullFileName = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
            imageList.Images.Add(i.ToString(), Bitmap.FromFile(fullFileName));
            metadata.Add(i.ToString(), new Metadata{Path = fullFileName});

            listView1.Items.Add(i.ToString(), "Image " + i, i.ToString());
        }

        // Update view
        listView1.Refresh();
        listView1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var filename = "1 ("+(i+2)+").png";
            var fullFileName = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
            // Change image
            imageList.Images.RemoveByKey(i.ToString());
            imageList.Images.Add(i.ToString(), Bitmap.FromFile(fullFileName));
            // Match metadata and image
            metadata[i.ToString()] = new Metadata{Path = fullFileName};
        }
        listView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var key = listView1.SelectedItems[0].ImageKey;

            label1.Text = metadata[key].Path;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "No image selected";
        }
    }
}

internal class Metadata
{
    internal string Path;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you for that clarification.  However, how would you go about inserting an image?

Comment: I think the problem with that is that the new image is added at the bottom of the list.  The requirement is to insert a new image somewhere in the middle of the list. For example, if list contains 8 items, and user selects 3rd item in list, they click a button to insert new image after the 3rd item.  Also, I need to store the filepath for each image.

Comment: @Kershaw: you need to set the sort order at the listview. And for the rest, keep an additional data structure. Don't use `Tag`, since it's not typed.

Comment: Thomas: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thomas:  your code sort of works.  Click button1 to load 10 images, but when you click button 2, it simply replaces ImageList images 4, 5, and 6 with images 5, 6, and 7.  And the list still has only 10 images.  I know for the purposes of example you updated 3 images.  But, what I need is: start with 10 images, select the 3rd image (or any image for that matter), click button2 to insert new image after the one selected, preserving the remaining 7, and end up with 11 items in the list.  Make sense?  In this test, I created 10 that are images of the numbers 1 thru 10 (127w x 165h).

Comment: FWIW: The lack of support for `Insert` should be seen as a clue that coders are not expected to do this. Indeed, there is no reason to:  Simply add the Image at end of list, create an item with that ImageIndex, and `Insert` the **item** in the desired location in `Items`, (Sometimes its better to answer a question with what coder should do instead. Or ask what their goal is, then point out a better way to get there.)